# Are there any issues I should watch for installing Delphi 7 on an XP machine with BDS2006 and XE installed already?

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-2006

I have a development PC where Delphi 2006 and XE are installed and co-existing quite happily.

I'm finishing up a job where the client needs to compile the sources, but still uses Delphi 7.  I am about to install D7 on my machine, so I can be sure what I send them is going to compile.

Are there any gotchas in doing this?  For instance I am currently paused at the screen where it asking for destination folders, and `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Borland Shared\` for shared files sounds just a little too "shared" for my liking.  I'm thinking it would be wise to create a new folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Borland Shared (D7)\` here.

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: @Ken.  I saw that one, but the issue here is going backwards - i.e. can installing an older version break an existing newer version?

Comment: I think David's answer addresses that (about the `PATH`, etc.), bue if you're in doubt you can always install into a virtual machine. (Removed suggestion about Win7 XP Mode; I missed that you said "on XP".)

Comment: My recommendation: create a virtual machine that closely matches the Delphi 7 client situation. Perform the build in that VM.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a direct answer to your question but I do not have enough reputation to comment yet so I will post here. I just found out that at windows azure microsoft does not charge you anything for a virtual machine that is shut down. You can install delphi versions on separate machines, work on them when you need to, which will only cost a few bucks, and shut it down again. Then, if you need a specific version to test a bit of code you are good to go.
Ps
I am in no way related to Microsoft. Just thought you may like to know.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I had pretty much decided that a VM was the way to go, though I've found the stability of VirtualBox VMs, which I use, a bit flaky sometimes - VM's that I had previously hibernated sometimes require a reboot when I come back to them later.  Interesting note re Azure though.  I had never looked at that before.